# How Generate an List from Volley stringRequest

Tags: java, android

I built an app using JSON files and Google Maps, and I need to know how to repeat an pattern for getting data from JSON using Volley `String Request`.

The idea is make this:

```
city.add(new LatLng(12.94695, 77.64058));
city.add(new LatLng(12.94735, 77.64076));
city.add(new LatLng(12.9476, 77.64081));
city.add(new LatLng(12.94786, 77.64078));
city.add(new LatLng(12.94809, 77.6407));
city.add(new LatLng(12.9483, 77.64058));
city.add(new LatLng(12.9486, 77.64029));
```

The way I'm using it, is not repeating city.

Add with every coordinate of the JSON list.

This is my intent:

```
 requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                urlAnim, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONArray AnimT = response.getJSONArray("rutasAnim");
                    for (int i = 0; i < AnimT.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object1 = AnimT.getJSONObject(i);

                        double latA = object1.getDouble("lat");
                        double lngA = object1.getDouble("lng");

                        city.add(new LatLng(latA, lngA));


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {...
```

I need to repeat this pattern: `city.add(new LatLng(latA, lngA));` with the different cities of the bd.

How can I do a `while` of the whole pattern?

For example, this should be the result (a style while like in PHP).

**Example of that I need:**

```
 requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                urlAnim, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONArray AnimT = response.getJSONArray("rutasAnim");
                    for (int i = 0; i < AnimT.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object1 = AnimT.getJSONObject(i);

                        double latA = object1.getDouble("lat");
                        double lngA = object1.getDouble("lng");

                        city.add(new LatLng(12.94695, 77.64058));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.94735, 77.64076));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.9476, 77.64081));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.94786, 77.64078));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.94809, 77.6407));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.9483, 77.64058));
                        city.add(new LatLng(12.9486, 77.64029));


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
```

My JSON File

```
{"rutasAnim": [{
            "anim":"city.add(new LatLng(6.3490548, -75.5580200));",
            "lat":"6.3490548",
            "lng":"-75.5580200"
        },{
            "anim":"city.add(new LatLng(6.3345438, -75.5671886));",
            "lat":"6.3345438",
            "lng":"-75.5671886"
        },{
            "anim":"city.add(new LatLng(6.3378121, -75.5700586));",
            "lat":"6.3378121",
            "lng":"-75.5700586"
        },{
            "anim":"city.add(new LatLng(6.3395342, -75.5656866));",
            "lat":"6.3395342",
            "lng":"-75.5656866"
        },{...
```

Comment: Would you please share the JSON result from the request.

Comment: Ready! I share Json result

Comment: are you asking how to put that data into a java list?

Answer (score 0):

if I got your question right. you want to get the list of `City Object` from the JSON. there to ways to do this:

1.similar to the one that you are doing right now:

```
public class City{
   String lat;
   String lng;

   public City(String lat, String lng){
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lng = lng;
   }

   public String getLat(){
       return lat;
   }
   public String getLng(){
       return lng;
   }
}
List<City> cities = new LinkedList<>();

requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            urlAnim, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray AnimT = response.getJSONArray("rutasAnim");
                for (int i = 0; i < AnimT.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object1 = AnimT.getJSONObject(i);

                    String latA = object1.getString("lat");
                    String lngA = object1.getString("lng");

                    cities.add(new City(latA , lngA ));


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
             //TODO Handle JSON Exception
           }
```

and you will have all your cities

2.use JSON parser Libraries which will do the parsing for you easier and sometimes quicker. for this, you can use the same City class and one of the libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)